# Equation of great circle which is perpendicular to some circle inside a $3$-sphere

Tags: riemannian-geometry, spheres, geodesic, tangent-spaces

Let $\mathbb{S}^3$ be the standard Euclidean sphere. Now we define shifted circle as
$$\mathbb{S}^1_f = \left\{\left(\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{2}},\dfrac{y}{\sqrt{2}},\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0\right): x^2+y^2 = 1\right\}$$ which is a submanifold of $\mathbb{S}^3$. I want to find the equation of great circle that passes through $P\in \mathbb{S}^1_f$ and is perpendicular to the $\mathbb{S}^1_f$.

---

**What I was trying to do**

- Equation of the tangent space at the point $P$.
- Then finding the normal to the tangent space at the point $P$
- Now find out the equation of the plane passing through $P$ whose normal vector is given (from step 2)
- Intersect with the $\mathbb{S}^3$ and it will give the equation of the great circle.

---

But the above-described method was very lengthy to compute. So is there any other method to compute this in general? I know, in general, the equation of the great circle is determined by two orthogonal points $P$ and $Q$, but how to describe all which are perpendicular to $\mathbb{S}^1_f$?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are there 4 coordinates in $\mathbb{S}^1_f$ - what is the $0$ for?

Comment: @Paul $S^3$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^4$, hence is described with $4$ components. As $S^1_f$ is a subset of $S^3$, it is still described with $4$ components

Comment: Sorry yes, just had $S^2$ in my head when I saw 'standard euclidean' for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $x_{0}$ and $y_{0}$ are real numbers with $x_{0}^{2} + y_{0}^{2} = 1$, so that $v_{0} := \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x_{0}, y_{0}, 1, 0)$ lies on the circle $S^{1}_{f}$. The vectors
\begin{align*}
  v_{1} &= (-y_{0}, x_{0}, 0, 0), \\
  v_{2} &= \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x_{0}, y_{0}, -1, 0), \\
  v_{3} &= (0, 0, 0, 1)
\end{align*}
are an orthonormal basis of $T_{v_{0}}S^{3}$ by inspection. The vector $v_{1}$ is tangent to the circle $S^{1}_{f}$, so $v_{2}$ and $v_{3}$ are perpendicular to the plane containing $S^{1}_{f}$. Your great circle may therefore be parametrized by
$$
(x, y, z, w) = (\cos t)v_{2} + (\sin t)v_{3} = (\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}x_{0}\cos t, \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}y_{0}\cos t, -\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cos t, \sin t).
$$

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I guess, the main problem with this methodology is that it will work for the example asked but if we want to ask the general question $(\mathbb{S}^k$ inside $\mathbb{S}^n)$ where the orthonormal basis is not easy to write.  I asked this problem keeping the general problem in my mind.

Comment: A question of this type does always boil down to linear algebra: If $S^{k}$ is the intersection of $S^{n}$ with an affine $(k+1)$-dimensional space at $P$, the orthogonal space at $P$ intersects $S^{n}$ in a great sphere $S^{n+k-1}$. Computationally, find a basis of $T_{P}S^{k}$ and orthonormalize (Gram-Schmidt at worst), extend to a basis of $\mathbf{R}^{n+1}$ and orthonormalize, and then use your favorite description of a sphere to describe the orthogonal great sphere. This is the procedure you outlined, but I'd proceed with bases rather than implicitly. What's best depends on your needs.

Comment: Thanks again. Just for the completion, if I want to see $\mathbb{S}^2_f$ inside $\mathbb{S}^5$ how do I find bases for the tangent space. The only thing I know is it is perpendicular to the point at which we want to find the tangent space. Following the above calculation, I need to find bases for the space $\{ax_0+by_0+cz_0 =0\} $. Can you please give a view on that? Probably, it will give me some flavor to see it in general.

Comment: To specify an affine $(k+1)$-dimensional space, it's usual to give either a point and a set of spanning vectors from that point, or else a non-homogeneous linear system of equations. In either case, standard algorithms (Gaussian elimination and/or Gram-Schmidt, depending on context) give the necessary bases or equations. It's hard to be more specific except by explaining how these algorithms work. :)

Comment: Thanks, for your explanantion. It really helped me a lot.